# assign port docker issue

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I am assigning port to my docker Image to run in browser but when I am assigning to port It gives me error like

by executing this command

`docker run -d -P 86:5000 secondphp2`

```
> Unable to find image '86:5000' locally docker: Error response from
> daemon: repository 86 not found: does not exist or no pull access. See
> 'docker run --help'.
```

This is my docker file

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
COPY / C:\wamp64\www\test
EXPOSE 86
```

I have successfully created Image with the name of `secondphp2`, I know that because when I run this command `docker ps -a` It gives me response like

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                                          NAMES
fe1840c962c4        secondphp2                "/bin/bash"              2 days ago          Exited (0) 2 days ago                                                     sleepy_bose
```

Is there something I am missing or any clue for me to solve this Issue?

**EDIT**

First I have created docker Image file from above docker file by using this command

```
docker build -t secondphp2 .
```

after running this command Image was successfully created

```
REPOSITORY                      TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
secondphp2                      latest              7968d546d5fd        2 days ago          346 MB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
docker run -d -p 86:5000 secondphp2
```

The `-P` (upper case) is not a valid flag. To expose port use `-p` in lower case.

The order of arguments passed to docker matters:

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

- OPTIONS: `-p 86:5000` and `-d` are options.
- IMAGE: `secondphp2`
- ARG: Arguments passed to be executed on the image (for example: `/bin/sh -l`)

Comment: tried that now It gives me error like ef5a7984ae0d471df16a3423a041247745fc5e43e3b6e25c5ba74b483ef6bd32
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"-p\": executable file not found in $PATH".

Comment: Are you sure that you have executed `docker run -d -p 86:5000 secondphp2`?  It seems that the docker image it's trying to run `-p` inside the container, and that's why it fails.

Comment: +1 for you more  Info, it really helpful me :) Now I am getting some random number but still port is not assigned, please check this http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2165075/1fd5d45d3e6f4a052655601c30bfe874

Comment: The port is not up in the container. The command is `/bin/bash`, and it does not bind any port, it's a shell. You should pass a command that starts a server, for example, `docker run -d -p 86:5000 secondphp2 nc -l 5000`. What's the command needed to start a server in your container? Pass it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not allowed to comment on your post, but the error it gives, makes me assume that you're not using the correct syntax when starting your docker. 
The docker agent is apparently trying to find version 5000 of an image named 86.

Can you show us what you're running to start the docker?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and +1 for your effort. but could you please elaborate in more start the docker means ? I am sorry for this I am new in docker so also I am using windows in docker in my system @ J. Meijers

Comment: Hey there, Sure, no problem! 
In the top snippet, you paste an error the docker daemon throws. What command did you run that returns this error? I believe there is something wrong with the command you are using. If this is also not clear enough, please explain to use exactly which steps you've taken to get to this error.

Comment: @KeyurShah great, this means the build succeeds, but I'm still missing the "docker run" command you're using:

since the error you've posted, also refers to docker run --help

Comment: for that I am running docker run -d -P 86:5000 secondphp2 , just updated my question sorry. @J. Meijers

Comment: can you try: docker run -d secondphp2 -p 86:5000 
I must say, I'm not sure if this is correct since I don't have a docker daemon here to try it out. But basically, the ordering of your command was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your continues effort :) now I am getting this response ef5a7984ae0d471df16a3423a041247745fc5e43e3b6e25c5ba74b483ef6bd32
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"-p\": executable file not found in $PATH".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135581/discussion-between-keyur-shah-and-j-meijers).